# issue with orientation

Tags: ios

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)) 
    {
        [self isPortraitSplash];
    }
    else if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation))
    {
        [self isLandScapeSplash];
    }
    return  YES;
}
```

In my methods `isPortraitSplash` and `isLandScapeSplash`, i am setting the frames for the view.

When orientation changes, it's always calling `isLandScapeSplash` - not able to call `isPortraitSplash` method.

Can any one advise me why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your existing `if` statement is comparing a `BOOL` to a `UIDeviceOrientation`.  Your test needs to be:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)) 
    {
        [self isPotraitSplash];
    }
    else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation))
    {
        [self islandScapeSplash];
    }
    return  YES;
}
```

`UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait` [returns a BOOL](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait), so that's all you need in your `if` statement condition.

**Update:** I will also add that I agree with the other answers that it's better to do this work in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`, instead of `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`.

**But, that isn't the reason your original code was failing.**  The original code was failing because of the `if` test comparing the `UIDeviceOrientation` to the `BOOL`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration` instead of `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`, it is guaranteed to be called before a rotation occurs.

Do not remove `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`, return YES for every orientation you want to support.

Answer (score 1):

First of all in

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

you have to declare which all orientations you want to support.

and in

```
- (BOOL)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)) 
    {
        [self isPotraitSplash];
    }
    else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation))
    {
        [self islandScapeSplash];
    }
}
```

you have to set the frames or any other for layout changes, and use like above.